# Ubuntu doesn't detect primary hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, installation, partitioning

Ubuntu isn't working well for me. I'm trying to install it, and all goes well...until I reach the choose partitions screen. It lets me select the drive i want to install Ubuntu to, but the only option on the list is the tiny 24 GB cache on my computer used to speed startup. I booted it live from a USB, and from the live booted OS it detected the drive, partitions on it, etc. What would I do to fix this? I also created an ~150gb partition that was empty before installing ubuntu. Still nothing.

And also, in case nobody posts and answer and I have to just install to the SSD, is it easily possible to use files from another disk than the installation disk in ubuntu? If I installed Ubuntu to the SSD, would it still be pretty simple to use files from the main hard disk?

I've also tried doing that `dmraid` thing, nothing happened (it said no raid disks). Also tried `sudo os-prober`. I did both of those through the live ubuntu.

And, as one last point, when I go to the "advanced" section of the partitioning page in the installer, it lets me select the main disk as the bootloader, so it obviously knows it's there

Comment: Did you try guided configuration, or manual configuration?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: When you reach the partition stage, you are asked whether you want do it all by yourself (manual), or following their suggestions (guided). Which did you choose?

Comment: suggestions, I'm pretty much a complete linux noob

Comment: I understand and I can relate to that. But I believe you would be offered the opportunity to install on a different disk only by choosing *manual*. Just try it, without really installing it, just to check whether I am right. You can always abort installation midway through the process, if you do not feel confident.

Comment: so, when it asks, I should choose "something else" instead of "alongside windows 8"? Also, I'm trying to perform a dual-boot, and I don't know how and don't want to go to the trouble of configuring a dual-boot manually. Or do you mean the "advanced" link on the choose partitions page?\